# Asymptotic distribution of a linear function

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Given a sequence of random variable $X_n$, $\sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu) \rightarrow^d N(\mu, \sigma^2) $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Let $g(X)$ be a continuous function. By the delta method, one can assert that:
$\sqrt{n}( g(\bar X) - g(\mu)) \rightarrow^d N (0, \frac{dg(\bar X)}{dX}^2 \sigma^2) $

However, given a linear function s.t, where $a, b$ $> 0$ and constant:

$a \sqrt{n}(\bar X - \mu) + b$.

How does this affect the asymptotic normal mean? i.e - how is ? changed $N (?, \frac{dg(\bar X)}{dX}^2 \sigma^2) $

Comment: You are asking the limit in distribution of $aZ_n+b$ if $Z_n\to N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. First, if the distribution of $Z$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, what is the distribution of $aZ+b$?

Comment: My assumption is that the answer is $N (a\mu + b, a\sigma^2) $ (i.e. $N(g(\mu), g'(\mu) \sigma^2)$. Is this to do with Slutsky's theorems?

Comment: I mean, of course, $N(a\mu + b, a^2\sigma^2)$, $N(g(\mu), g'(\mu)^2\sigma^2)$ above.